# construct the maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, estimation, maximum-likelihood

Let $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}$ be independent with a normal(0,1) distribution. Define $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}$ by $X_{1}=a_{1}$, $X_{2}=\theta X_{1}+a_{2}$ and $X_{3}=\theta X_{2}+a_{3}$ Find the MLE for $\theta$ .

My attempt: I get that $X_{1}$ has distribution $N(0,1)$, $X_{2}$ is $N(0,\theta^2+1)$ and $X_{3}$ is $N(0,\theta^4+\theta^2+1)$. Then I found the joint densisty and then the log likelihood function. Unfortunately, the expression is quite natsy and partial differentiation would involve simulataneous product, chain and quotient rule. This may be correct but can anyone confirm this is the right approach and the log likelihood function.

EDIT; The joint density of $X_{1},X_{2}, X_{3}$ I found to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi^3 (\theta^2+1)(\theta^4+\theta^2+1)}}exp(\frac{-1}{2}(x^2+\frac{x^2}{\theta^2+1}+\frac{x^2}{\theta^4+\theta^2+1})$

Comment: Are you referring to the joint density of $\{X_1, X_2, X_3\}$? Perhaps you should include it in the question.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Now updated

Comment: It seems that you are treating the three $X$'s as independent random variables. Are they?

Comment: Moreover, the joint density will be a tri-variate normal distribution. Is your task in the context of estimation from a multivariate distribution?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos My task is as  stated. I figured the $X_{i}$ are independent since the $a_{i}$ are. Can you show me your attempt?

Comment: So the r.v. $X_2 = \theta X_1+ a_2 = g(X_1) + a_2$ is independent of $X_1$, while at the same time being a function of $X_1$? Moreover, your task is not clearly stated: "find the MLE of $\theta$" using what sample? A sample of realizations of just one of the $X's$? And which one? A three-dimensional sample comprised of three-dimensional realizations from the random vector $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$? Other? ML estimation is shaped by the structure of the available (or hypothesized) sample.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos      an observation $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variables $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}$ are (standard) normal *and* independent. It follows that their joint probability distribution is tri-variate normal,
$$ \mathbf a = \left [\begin{matrix}\\
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
\end{matrix}\right] \sim \mathcal N_3 (\mathbf 0, \mathbf I_3)$$

where $\mathbf I_3$ is the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. The random vector of the $X$'s is an afine (linear) transformation of $\mathbf a$, $\mathbf X = \mathbf \Theta \mathbf a$ so it, too, will have a trivariate normal distribution:

$$ \mathbf X = \left [\begin{matrix}\\
X_1\\
X_2\\
X_3\\
\end{matrix}\right] = \left [\begin{matrix}\\
1 &  0& 0\\
\theta & 1 & 0\\
\theta^2 & \theta & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right] \cdot \left [\begin{matrix}\\
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
\end{matrix}\right] \sim \mathcal N_3 (\mathbf 0, \mathbf \Sigma)$$

with

$$ \Sigma = \Theta \Theta^T = \left [\begin{matrix}\\
1 &  \theta & \theta^2\\
\theta & \theta^2 +1 & \theta(\theta^2 +1)\\
\theta^2 & \theta(\theta^2 +1) & \theta^4+\theta^2+1\\
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Given just one realization $\mathbf x$ as the OP mentions in the comments, the density of the sample is

$$f_{\mathbf X} (\mathbf x) = (2\pi)^{-3/2}\cdot |\mathbf \Sigma|^{-1} \cdot \exp\left\{-\frac 12\mathbf x^T\mathbf \Sigma^{-1} \mathbf x\right\}$$

and the log-likelihood follows. Using the properties of the determinant you should quickly determine that $|\mathbf \Sigma| = 1$ and then find that the log-likelihood is just a 2nd-degree polynomial in $\theta$. The co-factor approach is the easiest one to calculate $\mathbf \Sigma ^{-1}$.